# Dyamic Linq -- strings to table and property names

Tags: linq

I've looked at the older Dynamic Linq library.  It doesn't suit my needs as far as I can tell as it primarily looks at returning query data (to which there are several examples of doing this dynamically).

I have a db table that contains the type, table, and column(property).  I would like to do dynamic inserts, such as:

```
var x = new _context.[table name as string from db];
x.[property name as string from db] = 4;
_context.Add(x);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Not sure if this is possible (or if so, how to go about with the implementation).

Comment: Linq is usually associated with queries, what you are trying to do is not a query.

Comment: If you have table names and properties you could consider using reflection to achieve your intended goal. But that is still too broad of a question.

Comment: Queries update and retrieve data.  I disagree that what I am trying to do is not a query.  You can save and retrieve values from Linq.  

Regarding reflection, yes, that makes sense but there still isn't a straight forward way to do this.

Comment: Queries retrieve, Commands insert, update or delete. If all you are doing is creating a new entity, populating it and adding/saving it to the table then that is a command. We may be nit picking about the technicality of the terminology used.

Comment: Yes, seem to be nitpicking over semantics.  I know what you're saying, but in the context I'm using I disagree that queries are retrieval only.  Regardless, one solution I have found is to use the createinstance extension method from https://csharp-extension.com/en/method/1002627/type-createinstance.  Since I know the type from the field in the db, this pretty much solves it.

Comment: Ok cool. Glad you found a solution. Happy coding.